# Textgeometry as object attribute

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently working on a project to create web components with three js. In order to do that I have to create objects for the different components.
I have several problems to create objects that have text as attribute.
I would like to add the mesh of the text in a THREE.Group() object in order to make it more accessible and usable if I need to add modifications.

```
var Button = {
    init : function(text, textSize, textFont, textMaterial, other attributes ...) {
        this._geo = new THREE.Group();
        this.createTextDesign(text, textSize, textFont, textMaterial);
        this._textMesh = this.createText()
        this._geo.add(this._textMesh);

        ...
    },

    createTextDesign : function() {
       this._text = text;
       this._textMaterial = textMaterial;
       this._textFont = textfont;

       if (textSize == "lg") {
            this._textSize = 2.5;
       } else if (textSize == "sm"){
            this._textSize = 1.5;
       } else if (textSize == "xs"){
            this._textSize = 1;
       } else {
            this._textSize = 2;
    },

    createText : function(){
        var text = null;
        var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        fontLoader.load('fonts/' + this._textFont + '.typeface.json', function(font) {
        var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(this._text, {
            font: font,
            size: this._textSize,
            height: this._textSize
        });
        fontLoader.load();

        text = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, this._textMaterial);
        });
        return text;
    },

    getGroup : function(){
        return this._geo;
    },

    ...
};
```

The problem is that when I try to instantiate this object with the following generic code (instantiate + display object) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js - ASCII Effect</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="components/Button.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var mat2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
            var mat3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
            var mat4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x0000ff} );

            var button = Object.create(Button);
            button.init("test", "lg", "optimer_regular", mat2, mat3, mat4);

            scene.add(button.getGroup());

            camera.position.z = 50;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error :

```
THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.         nullthree.js:10826:5
.add()                                                                three.js:10826
Button.init()                                                         Button.js:10
<anonymous>                                                           test4.html:31
```

With button.js:10 being the line where I add this._textMesh to this._geo.

I have also tried different techniques to create text meshes without using textLoader (for example : http://blog.andrewray.me/creating-a-3d-font-in-three-js/) but the text does not display, and I don't have any error message in the console...

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown simply because you are in fact not returning a mesh, but `null` from your `createText()`-method.

A simplified version of your code looks like this:

```
function createText() {
  var text = null;

  fontLoader.load(fontUrl, function(font) {
    text = createTextMesh(font);
  })

  return text;
}
```

Now, you need to be aware how async functions in javascript work. In this example, three things happen when you call `createText()`:

1. variable `text` is initialized as `null`
2. the request to load the font is *started*
3. the value of `text` (is always `null` at this point) is returned.

Why is that? The HTTP-Request takes (in terms of the speed of your code) ages to finally return a result. So that callback-function that receives the loaded font is called a long time after the value has already been returned. It still creates the mesh then, but the result isn't used anymore as the return did already happen.

There are some options to get around this problem, but in any case you will need to wait until the font is loaded before adding the object to the group.

You could try it like this:

```
function addTextMesh(parent) {
  fontLoader.load(fontUrl, function(font) {
    parent.add(createTextMesh(font));
  })
}
```

Or you make sure the font is already loaded before any of that happens.

One more note: I don't know about your use-case, but if you need to render a lot of text, using text-meshes could be a waste of resources (because of the huge number of vertices and computing involved in rendering them).

It might be a good idea to look at other alternatives for rendering text:

- render text to canvas and use that as a texture
- use something like bitmap-fonts: https://github.com/Jam3/three-bmfont-text

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer !
Although I would like some additional informations if you don't mind.
- You said "make sure that the font is already loaded". How can I preload the font ?  
- I tried the following for the createTextMesh(font) but the text still doesn't display :
`createTextMesh : function(font) {
        var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(this._text, {
            font: font,
            size: this._textSize,
            height: this._textSize
        });
        return new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, this._textMaterial);
    },`
Any idea why ?
Thanks !